# Creating a multi dimensional array at c

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

**Hello, need help creating a multi dimensional array
i am new at C, any help is appreciated.
this is the code**

```
#include <stdio.h>

char init_board(int row, int col);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        int row = argv[3];
        int col = argv[4];
        char** board = init_board(row, col);

        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                        printf("%d", board[i][j]);
                }
        }


        return 0;
}

char init_board(int row, int col) {

        int count = 0;
        int count2 = 0;
        char** out;
        while (count < row) {
                while (count2 < col) {
                        out[count][count2] = ".";
                        count2++;
                }
                count++;
                count2 = 0;
        }
        return out;
}
```

**any idea how i can fix this? what i am doing wrong?
when i compile i receive following warnings and when i run it says segmentation fault**

```
s@ss:~/s216/arc/ass1/ass1$ gcc ass1.c -std=c99 -o test
ass1.c: In function ‘main’:
ass1.c:6:12: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
  int row = argv[3];
            ^
ass1.c:7:12: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
  int col = argv[4];
            ^
ass1.c:8:17: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  char** board = init_board(row, col);
                 ^
ass1.c: In function ‘init_board’:
ass1.c:27:23: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
    out[count][count2] = ".";
                       ^
ass1.c:33:2: warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
  return out;
  ^
s@ss:~/s216/arc/ass1/ass1$ ./test x x 5 5
Segmentation fault
s@ss:~/s216/arc/ass1/ass1$
```

Comment: `int row = argv[3];` Left hand side is an `int`, right hand side is a `char *`. That are not compatible types - exactly as the warning tells you. You need to convert `argv[3]` to an int with something like `atoi` or better still `strtol`.

Comment: Maybe this is completely irrelevant, but if **everything is in bold**, then nothing really stands out.  Formatting is meant to draw attention to a specific part of the post, but if you draw attention everything, you may as well have drawn attention to nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Type of `argv[3]` and `argv[4]` is `char*`. Hence, the lines

```
int row = argv[3];
int col = argv[4];
```

are wrong. You are trying to initialize two `int` objects with `char*`.

If you run the program using:

```
program 10 20 30 40
```

then,

The value of `argv[0]` will be `"program"`.
The value of `argv[1]` will be `"10"`.
The value of `argv[2]` will be `"20"`.
The value of `argv[3]` will be `"30"`.
The value of `argv[4]` will be `"40"`.

Yes, they seem like they are numbers in the command line but they are strings in a C program. You can use `atoi` to extract the integral numbers from the strings.

```
int row = atoi(argv[3]);
int col = atoi(argv[4]);
```

Make sure to use

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

to get the declaration of the function.

Answer (score 1):

When you write `int row = argv[3];` you are making an int and initialising it to the value of `argv[3]`. However, `argv` is of type `char **`, which is a pointer to a pointer, or effectively an array of type `char *`. This is an invalid assignment, you need to make a char buffer to read the arguments in, then use `atoi(argv[i])` to get the integer value.

Answer (score 0):

the initially there was many errors with the code, i belive the following code is what it should have been..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char **init_board(int row, int col);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

        int row = atoi(argv[3]);
        int col = atoi(argv[4]);
        char** board = init_board(row, col);

        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                        board[i][j] = 'x';
                        printf("%c", board[i][j]);
                }
        }


        return 0;
}

char **init_board(int row, int col) {

        char** out = malloc(sizeof(char*) * row);
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) 
             out[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * col);

        return out;
}
```

Comment: Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. You can read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers)